# Get all available wifi

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I try to get detail about all available wifi but `BroadcastReceiver` for scan result not be called.

**code**

*Activity*

```
wifiStatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  WifiManager wifi;
  List<ScanResult> results;

  /* Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    wifi.startScan();
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        log.i("LOG","Scan Complete");
      }
    }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
  }
```

*Manifest*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

any suggest...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer.

1) need add two new permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

2) i don't know why but in my test device `Huawei honor P9 lite` location must be active.